# Python: Can't scan for the info needed to connect to a bluetooth device with PyBluez, even though the device is detected

Tags: python, bluetooth

I am using the PyBluez library to try to connect my computer to a bluetooth speaker. I am running windows 10.

When I use the discover_devices function, my speaker shows up just fine:

```
import bluetooth as bt

devices = bt.discover_devices(10, flush_cache=True, lookup_names=True, lookup_class=True)

for d in devices:
   print d
```

output:

```
('BB:B8:6D:D2:C1:6C', u'OontZ Angle 3 16C', 2360324) // this is my speaker
```

However, when I try to get information such as the port needed to connect to the device, it doesn't return anything at all:

```
devices = bt.discover_devices(10, flush_cache=True, lookup_names=True, lookup_class=True)

for d in devices:
    print d
    addr = d[0]
    print bt.find_service(address=addr) // this function returns info such as port, protocol, etc about devices
```

Output:

```
('BB:B8:6D:D2:C1:6C', u'OontZ Angle 3 16C', 2360324) // this is a speaker
[] // this should be a list of information about the device
```

Does anyone know what would cause this to happen? Here's some more information:

- If I just do a general bt.find_service() without specifying the mac address, the same thing happens
- Based on another post I saw, I am running pybluez-win10 instead of default pybluez. When running on the base version of pybluez, the code above gave the following error and stack trace:

> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bluetooth\msbt.py", line 243, in find_service
>
> > dresults = bt.find_service (addr, uuidstr)

> IOError: A

- This error has never showed up with pybluez-win10, but instead the output of the function is, as mentioned, empty.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you might need to install another version of Python, 3.5.4, and then download the wheel file specifically for this version of python.

wheel file [URL](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pybluez) and then use pip to install it: `pip install PyBluez‑0.22‑cp35‑none‑win_amd64.whl`